# How to count from two tables by using JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm doing the Q&A project so i have three tables related.
I want to list all users with which count all best answers they have.
Below are my tables and SQL

table **question**

```
id          | bestanswerid (index from table answer)
-----------------------
1           | 10
2           | 23
3           | 124
..          | ..
```

table **answer**

```
id          | userid (index from table user)
-----------------------
1           | 1
2           | 5
3           | 1
..          | ..
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT user.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS best_answer_count
FROM answer WHERE answer.id IN (
    SELECT bestanswerid 
    FROM question WHERE question.bestanswerid = answer.id
) AND answer.userid = user.id)
FROM user;
```

Its work but seems very slow, I want to use JOIN but got confused.
Please help or suggest to me, thanks.

Comment: An implicit join is already happening when you do question.bestanswerid = answer.id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
 SELECT user.*, COUNT(*) AS best_answer_count
 FROM answer
 LEFT JOIN user ON  answer.userid = user.id 
 LEFT JOIN question ON question.bestanswerid = answer.id 
 GROUP BY user.id
```

[simple fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/326f02/2)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple inner join if you only wanted the name and count

```
SELECT
     U.id,
     COUNT(BAC.bestanswerid)
FROM user U
INNER JOIN BAC
   ON U.id = BAC.userid;
```

Comment: The performance issue here is that the code in question uses what is called a "correlated subquery." In other words, the subquery used in the WHERE clause must be evaluated for each row in the `answer` table (because it contains a reference to one or more columns in in `answer` table, whose values depend on the specific row being considered).

Comment: Sounds alright to me, I don't know much about how mysql plans it's queries but joins are for the most part better than nested queries

Comment: Absolutely, JOIN is efficient and should be used wherever appropriate.

I would point out, thought, that some subqueries only need to be evaluated once, and they are not nearly so damaging to performance as the example in the question.